# Does the order of iteration affect the answer returned by FIND-S?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning

This paragraph is from the book *Machine Learning* by *Tom M.Mitchell* (Page 26):

> 1. Initialize $h$ to the most specific hypothesis in $H$
> 2. For each positive training instance $x$ 
>    $\;\;\;\;\;\;$.For each attribute constraint $a_i$, in $h$ 
>    $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$If the constraint $a_i$, is satisfied by $x$ 
>    $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$Then do nothing 
>    $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$Else replace $a_i$, in $h$ by the next more general constraint that 
>    $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$is satisfied by $x$
> 3. Output hypothesis h

Now, If there is more than one maximally specific hypothesis consistent with the set $D$ of training examples, Does the order of iteration on the training examples affect the answer returned by this so-called *FIND-S* algorithm? I think the answer would be yes but I haven't been able to find an example yet.